# How to handle cancellationToken.cancel for Task.delay in c#?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have an method in which I am using Task.Delay for 1 minute. So when I want to try cancel that Task then it's giving me error like `system.threading.tasks.taskcanceledexception a task was canceled` instead of cancel that Task.

So how can I cancel that Task with handle this error.

```
public static System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();

tokenSource.cancel();
```

```
public static async void waitForSignal(System.Threading.CancellationToken token)
{
       await Task.Delay(60000, token);  //here I am getting error while I am defining tokenSource cancel.
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is what happens [when you cancel a task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation). Exceptions are handled with `try catch`.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting this to do? You create a token then cancel it and then wonder why you can't delay it? This code doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: Maybe the [`WaitOne` method of the `WaitHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone?view=netframework-4.8) is what you actually after?

Comment: @Liam, Actually admin is getting signals from wcf service in which if admin will not get expected signals from wcf then it will wait for 60 seconds and if admin will get expected numbers of signals in first 10 seconds then it will not required to wait for next 50 seconds. So I need to use cancellationtoken for cancel the task.

Comment: Which WaitOne will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how can I cancel that Task with handle this error.

You're already canceling the task; you just need to handle the error:

```
try
{
  await Task.Delay(60000, token);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
}
...
```

> Actually admin is getting signals from wcf service in which if admin will not get expected signals from wcf then it will wait for 60 seconds and if admin will get expected numbers of signals in first 10 seconds then it will not required to wait for next 50 seconds.

Sounds like what you want is a *signal*, not a *cancellation*. You want to (asynchronously) wait for either a signal or a time period (delay), after which you want to take some action. You don't really want cancellation here.

One kind of asynchronous signal is `TaskCompletionSource<T>`. Your action code can `await` the `Task` of that TCS, and the signaling code can call `SetResult` to send the signal. Something like this:

```
public static TaskCompletionSource<object> signal = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

...

signal.SetResult(null);

...

public static async Task waitForSignal(Task signalTask)
{
  await Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(60000), signalTask);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply. Once if we cancel Task using tokenSource.cancel() method then is it possible to run it again ?

Comment: In my scenario I am cancelling Task using CancellationTokenSource so when next time I want to call that method then it's giving me result like Token.IsCancellationRequested = true but actually I need to make it false. I try to change it but it's showing read only property. So can you guide me that how can I make CancellationRequester false ?

Comment: A cancellation token can only be canceled once. If you need another cancellation token, you should create another `CancellationTokenSource`.